# NDB PolyModel Problems

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, polymodel

I'm working on a google app engine app in which we use polymodel to express a subset of the entities. I'm having problems using it in the way that the docs claim it works though.

My first problem is that I noticed that a call on an 'inherited' method on an entity that is the type of the subclass is instead calling the parent polymodel's version of that method, which is just a 'pass'. Thus the method returns None and messes everything up.

EDIT: 
It appears that this is the case not just for the method call, but for all of it's properties. When I try to log some specific info that the subclass has but the parent doesn't, it throws an error saying that it can't find that info.

e.g.

```
class Parent(polymodel.PolyModel):
    def someMethod(self, params):
        pass

class Child(Parent):
    def someMethod(self, params):
        {{logic}}
        return something
```

The second problem I found, as a result of trying to solve the first, is that the 'class_name()' method, which is reported to exist here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/polymodel,
does not seem to work.

When I call it, I get a server error that ends with `AttributeError: 'Parent' object has no attribute 'class_name'`. My class is not actually called 'Parent', I just wanted to keep consistent with my earlier example.

It's all very frustrating, and I don't really know how to proceed. Any help appreciated!

**EDIT**

Here is perhaps a more detailed description of what is happening:

I have defined a polymodel class that I do not want to instantiate; I only want it to serve as a template class. It has template methods that I want to be defined in all of it's children; all are `pass`. It lives in my main models file

```
class Template(polymodel.PolyModel):
    def method_one(self):
        logging.error("ENTERED TEMPLATE METHOD, THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN")
        pass

    def method_two(self):
        logging.error("ENTERED TEMPLATE METHOD, THIS SHOULD NOT HAPPEN")
        pass
```

In another file, lets call it template_extension_models.py, in the same directory as the main models file, I've defined an extension of the Template model that populates it's methods with real logic.

```
class TemplateExtension(Template):
    def method_one(self):
       """
       some logic specific to this class, actually
       takes inputs and returns something
       """

    def method_two(self):
       """
       some logic specific to this class, actually
       takes inputs and returns something
       """
```

Back in the main models file, we have certain classes that have ndb.KeyProperties that point to 'Template'. The hope/assumption is that this will act like other inheritance models, and so when we pull from the datastore an entity of type/subtype of 'Template', we can call it's method_one() and method_two() and the code for that specific instance's method_one and method_two will run. i.e.

```
 class OtherThing(ndb.Model):
     template = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Template)

     def get_template_and_call_method(self):
         template = self.template.get()
         res = template.method_one()
         do_something_with(res)
```

Here is where my problem is happening. We never actually use Template; for each instance of 'OtherThing', we are actually assigning an instance of TemplateExtension. Yet, randomly, **not every time**, after pulling out the template in OtherThing's method (a generalization of several places in my actual code), I see the method of the Template parent class being called instead of the TemplateExtension class, which causes a ton of errors. Since this doesn't happen every time, I'm not sure where to begin looking for the problem.

Comment: For your first problem, provide the code that isn't working - just the models doesn't help much. The documentation you've linked to is very old, and refers to the 'db' package, not ndb. The principles about how PolyModel works still apply, but the code specifics are different.

Comment: I would suggest as per previous comments you show the code calling the methods in addition to the class definitions.  I use Polymodel extensively (in db, and ndb) for many years and it works as expected wrt inheritance.

Comment: @TimHoffman - I cannot show the actual code because it's a really big code base and the problem is spread out, and because I don't want to reveal sensitive information about my company's architecture. I wrote something more general above, but tried to give a lot of detail. What do you think?

Comment: Hmm, well you will need to do some basic debugging. Try logging the class when you retrieve an entity. Maybe you're retrieving the parent class instances.

Comment: Based on logging that I've already done, it is the instance of the class that I want, but it is being 'treated' as an instance of it's polymodel parent. As in, function calls on the instance call it's parent's methods, which are mostly 'pass'.

Answer (score 2):

It's called `_class_name()` with a leading underscore.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/polymodelclass